# Why does my web application I have published as an executable in Visual Studio not do anything?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

My friend has asked me for a copy of a very simple web application that I made for them in ASP.NET Core 3.1.  I thought I would make life easier and just send him this as an executable that could run on his computer without the need for all the source code and project files.

I published web application as a Windows Application on the .NET Core 3.1 framework.  I defined my publishing profile as:

```
Configuration: Release
TargetFramework: netcoreapp3.1
DeploymentMode: Self-Contained //This seems logical as to avoid him having to install sdks
TargetRuntime: win-x64 //He runs windows 10 64 bit pro
File Publish Options: 
    Produce single file //I thought this would reduce the clutter of files
    Delete all existing files prior to publish
Databases:
    Use this connection string at runtime
    Data Source=CarHires.db //using sqlite


Publish Method: File System
Target Location: <my defined directory>
```

The publish process works just fine and the application is created with an executable, the problem is...it doesn't do anything, when you run it, the process will appear in the task manager but nothing happens, it just sits there until I end it.

Have I done something wrong here or is what I'm trying to do not valid?  If this isn't the way to do this, is there any other way I can create an exe from my web app?

Comment: What would you expect it to do? Typically a web app is accessed via browser, so probably that exe is just creating a webserver ...

Comment: Did you try accessing it over HTTP? By default I think it would listen on port 5000; can you curl http://localhost:5000 or access that in a browser?

Comment: My expectation was in fact for it to just launch a browser, the webserver and start the application.